# PHP Redirect to different pages after form submit (depends on what you write)

Tags: php, html, redirect, submit, jpeg

So I am making a page where you fill in the form, and depending on what you write, you will be redirected to different pages that contains different pictures. So for example if I write "tulip.jpg" and press submit, a page with the picture named tulip.jpg will appear. And if I write "bear.jpg", the page with the picture named bear.jpg will appear. Sorry I'm not good at explaining. So I have made the main page, but I don't know what to type in the variables to make different pictures appear when you write different things. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP - oppgave 6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Om bilder</h1>
        <form method="get" action="oppgave6b.php">
        <p>Skriv inn et filnavn - ikke glem filutvidelsen - og klikk på knappen</p>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Send forespørsel">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

6b:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP - oppgave 6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $link = <img src="Tulipaner.jpg">;
            $link = '<img src="rod.jpg">';
            echo "<h1>Du valgte følgende bilde:</h1>";
            echo "$link";
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried writing any code?

Comment: Can you post what is in oppgave6b.php please?

Comment: added it now @Ray

Comment: Added it now @PhilipThomson

Comment: Can you....try to solve the problem and we will help? Hint: your PHP page, where you submit the form to should have some PHP code at the top where you can grab the request data and redirect as you need to. Or create an `<img>` and use PHP to echo the `src` attribute from the form data.

Comment: i updated the 6b, that's what i would guess, but it doesent work :(( @Ray

Comment: so what if I don't type baer/jpg ?   why not use a select dropdown?

Comment: Check Philips answer, his is or very close to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be like so:

index.html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP - oppgave 6</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Om bilder</h1>
        <form method="get" action="oppgave6b.php">
        <p>Skriv inn et filnavn - ikke glem filutvidelsen - og klikk på knappen</p>
            <input type="text" name="submission">
            <input type="submit" value="Send forespørsel">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your PHP file oppgave6b.php:

```
<?php
    $incomingvalue = $_GET["submission"];

    if($incomingvalue == 'tulip.jpg')
    {
        echo '<img src="tulip.jpg"/>';
    } 
    if($incomingvalue == 'bear.jpg')
    {
        echo '<img src="bear.jpg"/>';
    }
?>
```